# how using if inside public object C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, umbraco

I'am new using C# and i have problem when using if inside "public object" method, this my code :

```
public object Login([FromBody] MailParameters data)
    {

        UmbracoDatabase db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
        var select = new Sql("SELECT UserID FROM Users where Email='" + data.Email + "';");
        var ids = db.Fetch<listUsersChecks>(select);

        if (ids)
        {
        var getByEncrypt = new Sql("SELECT * FROM Users where Email='" + data.Email + "' AND password='" + data.Password + "';");
        var listue = db.Fetch<listUsers>(getByEncrypt);
        }else{
            var listue = "";
        }
        return listue;
    }
```

the output is :

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<LoginController.listUsersChecks>' to 'bool'
```

the error is in `if(ids){` , how to solved this?

thanks

Comment: what exactly is `if (ids)` supposed to check? if there are any elements?

Comment: This code should not be used in production. It is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Knelis thanks for advice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error message, `if` statement required a Boolean, but you feed in with a List. In this case, your `ids` is a list `List<LoginController.listUsersChecks>`

Since it's a list, you can check by counting number of item in this list:

`if(ids.Count >0){} else{}`

Comment: wow..i have try to use operator like == and != but not work.. and i don't know if the ids can use count.. thanks for help.

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah be familiar with type, because C# is strong-type :)

Comment: Personally I dislike using `var` for variable type declaration. Yeah, its sorter, but I like looking at first glance the data types. If you are new to c# I would suggest not using `var` until you get used to the language. If you had declared `List<listUsersChecks> ids = db.Fetch<listUsersChecks>(select);` it would have been easier to detect because a `List` is not a `bool` variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = db.Fetch<listUsersChecks>(select);
```

This will give you a `List<listUsersChecks>` and an `if` condition needs a `bool` to evaluate if it should be executed or not.

If you want to execute the `if` statement when you have entries in your list you should use

```
if(ids.Count > 0)
{
    //logic
}
```

`Count` is a property of `List` and gives the number of items in the list.

To make it even more clearer you could write this as well.

```
bool hasItems = ids.Count > 0;
if(hasItems)
{
    //logic
}
```

You could use the `Any` method of LINQ as well.

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
>   condition.

That would look like

```
if(ids.Any())
{
    //logic
}
```

For more information have a look at [101 LINQ-Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: `ids.Any()` would also be a possibility

Answer (score 0):

not all your code paths return a value. you have to define your return object prior to the if statement and inside each branch just set it.and as for ids, it's not a valid boolean expression by itself, you may try ids.Any()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting C# to support  "truthy" and "falsey" values like Javascript. In C#, there is no concept of "truthy" or "falsey". The expression in the `if` must evaluate to a boolean `true` or `false`. What you really want to do is use something like this Linq expression:

```
if(ids.Any())
{
    ...
}
```